# Python 3, variable referenced before assigned but it is assigned

Tags: python

So I'm coding a program that uses a database, this databases stores a dictionary.
To store the dictionary in a **.db** file I use pickle.

Everything is good, but when running the code, this error message comes up.

```
line 23, in save_data
pickle.dump(database,datafile)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'database' referenced before assignment
```

`save_data()` is a function which does save the file but before posting the code I would like to post the whole section.

```
if com == "agregar": # "com" stands for command
    print("Escribe el nombre y el dinero del sujeto en cuestion")
    tempname = str(input("Nombre: "))
    tempvalue = int(input("Dinero: "))
    load_data()
    print(database,"hey") #Print intended for debug
    if tempname in database:
        database[tempname] += tempvalue 
    else:
        database[tempname] = tempvalue
    save_data()
```

Excuse the Spanish, I'm writing this code for somebody who talks Spanish.

The `load_data()` is self-explanatory, it loads the data file to a database variable

```
def load_data():
global database
with open(namedata, "rb") as datafile:
    try:
        database = pickle.load(datafile)
    except EOFError:
        database = {}
```

`Save_data()`:

```
def save_data():
with open(namedata, "wb") as datafile:
    pickle.dump(database,datafile)
del database
```

So you see the **Print intended for debug** I wrote up there?, yeah, that one.
When the code is run, this is printed

```
Escribe el nombre y el dinero del sujeto en cuestion
Nombre: Jon
Dinero: 1000
{} hey
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex33.py", line 97, in <module>
   main()
File "ex33.py", line 93, in main
   main2(tempcom)
File "ex33.py", line 63, in main2
   save_data()
File "ex33.py", line 23, in save_data
  pickle.dump(database,datafile)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'database' referenced before assignment
```

So this is saying database is declared so it can be printed (database = {}), but in the save_data() function is isn't? even though, the variable is global?
Also, experimenting, I replaced the **save_data()** function with it's contents

```
    if com == "agregar":
    print("Escribe el nombre y el dinero del sujeto en cuestion")
    tempname = str(input("Nombre: "))
    tempvalue = int(input("Dinero: "))
    load_data()
    print(database,"hey")
    if tempname in database:
        database[tempname] =  database[tempname] + tempvalue 
    else:
        database[tempname] = tempvalue
    with open(namedata, "wb") as datafile:
        pickle.dump(database,datafile)
    del database
```

This happens :

```
Escribe el nombre y el dinero del sujeto en cuestion
Nombre: danny
Dinero: 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex33.py", line 99, in <module> 
  main()
File "ex33.py", line 95, in main
  main2(tempcom)
File "ex33.py", line 58, in main2
  print(database,"hey")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'database' referenced before assignment
```

print(database, "hey") cannot be printed anymore, but why?
there are others function that use save_data() and load_data() and these work correctly, example

```
    if com == "list":
    print('Elige un nombre o escribe "completa" para mostrarla entera')
    templistcom = str(input("> "))
    load_data()
    while templistcom not in database:
        if templistcom == "completa": return
        print("Esta entrada no existe")
        templistcom = str(input("> "))
    if templistcom == "completa":
        for key in database:
            print(key, ":" ,database[key])
    else:
        print(templistcom, ":", database[templistcom])
    save_data()
    =============================================================
ex33.py
File Created[REG]
Bienvenido
Selecciona un comando
['list', 'agregar', 'registro', 'salir']
Comando: list
Elige un nombre o escribe "completa" para mostrarla entera
> Ken
Esta entrada no existe
> complta
Esta entrada no existe
> completa
Quieres salir?
si / no
> si
```

As you can see, this code executes database save_data, load_data and it does launches errors. I have been looking for answer but I haven't been able to locate a valid one, please help.
If I didn't make me clear, I  will try to express myself better, after all, English isn't my native lenguage.

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: You didn't declare `global database` *in* `save_data()`, so it doesn't know it is global (and fix your indentation).

Comment: The global declaration in save_data() worked, thank you, the indentation may look wrong because I copied-pasted wrong and I had to indent with the spacebar. Thanks